# Use Tapestry with Primefaces?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces, tapestry

Is it possible to use Tapestry together with Primefaces?
I wonder because primefaces uses xhtml tags to build the webpage. And tapestry does not use xhtml but own *tml file format.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well...

Since Tapestry is actually an alternative MVC framework to JSF (you can choose JSF or Tapestry  , but not both), so the answer is **NO**, you either go with JSF as your MVC framework + Primefaces as component suite, or choose Tapestry as your MVC framework.

See [Java Server Faces 2.0 or Tapestry 5.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831807/java-server-faces-2-0-or-tapestry-5-2)